# (out of the blue) "not authorized" message when trying to do push/pull/fetch

Tags: eclipse, tfs, egit, azure-devops

I tried to do a push of a commit to a git repository with egit in eclipse yesterday, and since then I'm getting "not authorized" popup (All of a sudden). This is not machine related, as I checked couple hours later(when error persisted) on my laptop, which I didn't touch in 2 days (and it was working perfectly then), and I am getting the same error.

I can connect with Team Foundation Server just fine, and my access was not reverted. Would any of you have any idea what might be the cause of the problem?

Just for further information, when doing operations (in Eclipse) on a project that is under TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control), I can do check-in just fine, so that is a proof my authorization to the server was not reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully I found the cause.

For those who will encounter the same problem, there must have been a change (a bug fix most likely) in TFS server implementation on Microsoft servers. Previously I logged in using my webbrowser login, and also my password did not fullfill the requirements - I did not have at least 1 uppercase letter. Once I change my password and entered my alternate credential in eclipse, all worked correctly.